# VBA - how to dynamically access userform

Tags: excel, vba

do you know a method to access userform which name is stored in a variable?
I have class module with events for checkboxes, but checkboxes are located on different userforms and I need to operate with them or theirs userforms.

Class module have its public variable chbParent, which is userform name. Lets say that

```
chParent = "formCmnStructs"
```

Then inside of class module I have this (and more operations where condition is required):

```
If chbParent = "formInsertRow" Then
  Divisions(r, c).Checked = IIf(formInsertRow.Controls("chbDiv_" & Me.chbId).value = True, 1, 0)
  formInsertRow.chbDivClicked
ElseIf chbParent = "formCmnStructs" Then
  Divisions(r, c).Checked = IIf(formCmnStructs.Controls("chbDiv_" & Me.chbId).value = True, 1, 0)
  formCmnStructs.chbDivClicked
End If
```

Now it is used for two forms only, but more is comming. Is there any way to cancel condition and acces userform dynamically like this:

```
userforms(chbParent).Controls("....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use public variable like `ActiveForm as object` and for each userform

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Set ActiveForm = Me

End Sub
```

And then in class module
`ActiveForm.Controls("...` 
 
To get the form name `chParent = ActiveForm.Name`